# Android GoogleMap V2 on zoom map doesn't get sharpen

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm currently working on Android and have started with Google Maps V2 API.
As I have finished going through all [their setup guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api) the map worked and I was able to see the continents. Only problem is that when I zoom in, the map stays the same I just get less pixels untill eventually I get gray squares - as if it has loaded the map but not entirely. I'd been looking around for someone with a problem like mine and couldn't find any.
Any assistance will be appreciated.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>


public class myMapActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }
```

More information:
I had added:
`GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);`

and gotten gray squares without map at all.
 hope it helps identify the problem 
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens after you uninstall and then install the app again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended I had uninstalled which probably removed previous save of the map.
After reinstalling the app works fine.